# We could not sign you in to xbox live 0x800705020 /windows account

Tags: windows-10, xbox360

I can't sign in to my windows /Xbox live account on my windows 10 computer app,

[image]

I believe it might have something to do with the fact I've used Spybot anti-beacon and Destroy-Windows-10-Spying

[image]

Update:
i never delete the windows 10 metro apps in dws would this effect the sign in
DWS.

[image]

Comment: Your assumption is correct.  Reverse all changes made by the product and remove it

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  We are always glad to help, but please let me make one rather strong recommendation:  we have seen *countless* questions within the Stack Exchange realm from people who have encountered problems after using one of these programs similar to "Destroy-Windows-10-Spying."  Those applications tend to do very little that you can't already do within the Windows 10 settings interface, and quite often they are the cause of more harm than good.

Comment: Update your question to include the protection settings, you failed to mention the use of DWS, that changes everything.

Comment: When you provide screenshots of an application, please provide the entire application window, your screenshots don't include all the require information.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe it might have something to do with the fact I've used Spybot anti-beacon and Destroy-Windows-10-Spying

While that particular program, has extremely destructive behavior and should never be used, it isn't the cause of your problems.  You deleted the Xbox UWP application or even worse the required service, through the use of an even more destructive application, DWS.

> I never delete the windows 10 metro apps in DWS would this affect the sign in DWS.

Based on the screenshot you provided that did in fact happen.  The only solution to this problem is to reinstall Windows 10.

> [image]